# How to output a double that is the value of a number multiplied by another variable in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, floating-point, double, output

I'm trying to get an output for my `weight_Fee` using `double`, and I cannot seem to get the correct value.  I have tried using `float`, but I haven't been able to get that to work either.

My goal is to get an output value containing two decimal places as if I were to be calculating a cost, but I get 0.00 every time.

I'm new to C++, so if anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, it would be a big help.  Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {

double animal_Weight;   
double weight_Fee = .5 * animal_Weight;

cout << "In rounded poundage, how much does your animal weigh? ";
cin >> animal_Weight;

cout << setprecision (2) << fixed << weight_Fee;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The variable `animal_Weight` is undefined and can be initialized to anything by the compiler or the operating system or whatever value happen to be last in the memory.

Comment: Also, after you input data, the `weight_Fee` is not calculated again.  I recommend moving the definition of `weight_Fee` to after you input `animal_Weight`.

Comment: Statements are executed in order. How do you expect the multiplication to work *before* you ask for the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double weight_Fee = 0.5 * animal_Weight;
```

When you initialize `weight_Fee` like that you are setting it equal to 0.5 * the current value of animal_Weight. Since this is currently undefined `weight_Fee` will be some garbage value.

When you set `animal_Weight` to something based on user input later on, that won't change the value of a previous variable. You'll have to use that statement again to set `weight_Fee` = 0.5 * the **current** value of `animal_Weight`

The best thing to do is probably to just declare `weight_Fee` at the top, and not define it until you have set `animal_Weight` to what you want it to be.

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    double animal_Weight;   
    double weight_Fee;

    cout << "In rounded poundage, how much does your animal weigh? ";
    cin >> animal_Weight;

    weight_Fee = .5 * animal_Weight

    cout << setprecision (2) << fixed << weight_Fee;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `animal_Weight` is undefined and can be initialized to anything by the compiler or the operating system or whatever value happen to be last in the memory.

You need to calculate `weight_Fee` after you input a value for `animal_Weight`:

```
double animal_Weight = -1.0;   

cout << "In rounded poundage, how much does your animal weigh? ";
cin >> animal_Weight;
double weight_Fee = .5 * animal_Weight;

cout << setprecision (2) << fixed << weight_Fee;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either someone forgot to mention to you that your computer does only 1 instruction at a time (and the C++ compiler generates instructions in a sequence corresponding to your code); or perhaps you've never grok'ed the statement.

```
1) double animal_Weight;   
2) double weight_Fee = .5 * animal_Weight;

3) cout << "In rounded poundage, how much does your animal weigh? ";
4) cin >> animal_Weight;

5) cout << setprecision (2) << fixed << weight_Fee;
```

Your code prompts for (3) and cin's (4) an animal weight.   ok.

But the weight_Fee was computed (2) prior to knowing the animal_Weight (4). This is a logic error.

So if the computation at (2) did not know the animal_Weight, the correct value simply can not be determined.

Also, the animal_Weight (1) is not initialized, creating undefined behaviour.

---

Note that you *CAN* get the compiler to complain about (generate a warning) the attempted use of an uninitialized variable (at line 2), but you have to command the compiler to do so (by using an option).